# Merge two dataframes based on same column value

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do vlookup in pandas like in excel. In other words:

- If there are same values in both columns (B and C) then print it in new column D (while keeping column A).
- In any other case put NaN

I did: `vlookup = df1.merge(df2, on = 'A')` but it copies the column value of B and puts everywhere.

```
df1 = 

A      B

car    VB
car    K2
car    V9
car    VX
```

---

```
df2 = 

A      C

car    VB
car    K2
cat    BN
monkey AS
```

---

Desired output:

```
df3 = 
A      D      

car    VB     
car    K2     
cat    NaN
car    NaN    
cat    NaN
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
df3=df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'C':'B'}),on=['A','B']).rename(columns={'B':'D'})
     A   D
0  car  VB
1  car  K2
```